# Requirement to carry driver's license and registration in Massachusetts

Tags: driving, massachusetts

I was reading Chapter 90 in the Massachusetts General Laws and I could not find any provision requiring an operator to carry a driver's license and registration documents in the vehicle while operating it. Is it illegal in Massachusetts to operate a vehicle while not carrying a license and/or registration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Chapter 90 Section 11](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartI/TitleXIV/Chapter90/Section11):

> Every person operating a motor vehicle shall have the certificate of registration for the vehicle and for the trailer, if any, and his license to operate, upon his person or in the vehicle, in some easily accessible place [...]

According to the state's ["Schedule of Assessments for Civil Motor Vehicle Infractions"](http://www.mass.gov/courts/docs/courts-and-judges/courts/district-court/citable-civil-motor-vehicle-offenses.pdf), violation of the license or registration requirements of this section are each punishable by an assessment of $35, $75, or $150 for first, second, or third offenses; plus a $5 public safety surcharge in each case.